# Detect java error in Hudson execution

Tags: java, hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

I'am executing an java script in Hudson server. I want throw new error if the java fail but I dont know how to do it. I want to throw new error because I configured send new email when the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW5r0.jpg)error throw.

Comment: Are you using Java (as tagged) or JavaScript  (as given in the description)?

Comment: How are you launching your Java application? (Is it a Hudson plug-in or something you call via a script or through maven?)

Have you tried using System.exit(1) when your Java application fails?

Comment: Hi, I use "java -jar" in Hudson task, I dont tried using System.exit(1), do is the solution?

Comment: Thanks, System.exit(1) is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is notify to the VM that the process failed, the way is: System.exit(1) (in catch block)